# How to replace a portion of a dynamic php string

Tags: php, mysql, echo, str-replace

I have a page that is calling dynamic URL content from MySQL via Primary ID. The information is being called and echoed as

```
"../images/icons/filename.jpg"
```

via this command:

```
<php echo $row_getimages['icon']; ?>
```

I want to change "../images/icons/filename.jpg" to:

```
"http://www.mysite.com/images/icons/filename.jpg"
```

Does anyone know if this is possible with a str_replace or some other command? I have tried that particular one but I am having trouble figuring out the proper syntax.

Comment: Can you show the exact code you have tried? Would help us help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can user [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<?php echo str_replace("../","http://www.mysite.com/",$row_getimages['icon']); ?>
```

Just make sure you have the parameters in the correct order:

Comment: Worked like a charm, it was just my order that was fudging me up. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php echo str_replace('../','http://www.mysite.com/',$row_getimages['icon']); ?>
```